# Object reference not set to an instance of an object Error? Registry editing

Tags: vb.net, registry

I have done this before with no errors but I am creating a Servicing program, and now I am getting this error.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Whats the problem, if you need more information just reply or email me and hopefully I will get it.

Here is the code I am trying to execute with no success:

```
Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser
Dim subkey As RegistryKey
subkey = key.OpenSubKey("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting", True)
subkey.SetValue("Disabled", 1)
```

Comment: guessing: key is null

Comment: Is it a 64-bit app? Check the `\Wow6432Node` (I believe ...) in the registry.

Comment: Yes its a 63-bit app (and can you explain maybe a little further on the error?

Comment: **The Key Wow6432Node is empty**

Comment: Are you able to visually see the key where you expect it to be in the Registry?

Comment: As I said before I have never had this problem before while trying to add program to startup

Comment: SORRY MEANT ITS A 64 BIT APP